# how to use 对此 in a sentence?

Tags: translation, sentence-structure

What do you think should be done about it?
你觉得对此该做什么？

this is the translation online I found for this English sentence. The translation makes some sense, but I'm not quite sure what the point of "对此" is. I know it means "towards this" but I don't know why it's used here.

Comment: Best to avoid in orally, especially for learners, unless your pronunciation is absolutely spot on it's going to be hard for anyone to guess that you would be using such a formal word like 对此.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *but I'm not quite sure what the point of "对此" is. I know it means "towards this" but I don't know why it's used here.*

'**此**(this)' short for '此事(this affair)'. It is the **pronoun** for the **topic** that's preceded the sentence itself.

[topic]: "老师们正在威胁罢工" - "teachers are threatening to strike"

[comment]: "你觉得**对此**该做什么?" - what you think should be done **toward (about) it**?"

> **此**(事) is the pronoun for **this** (affair) : **teachers are threatening to strike**

[topic]+[comment] is a common sentence structure, if you don't use the pronoun for the topic, you would end up with sentence like this:

> "**老师们正在威胁罢工**, 你觉得对[**老师们正在威胁罢工**]该做什么?"
>
> - *In this case, you can just omit the topic and make "你觉得对老师们正在威胁罢工该做什么?" a complete sentence on its own*

It is just common sense to not repeat the topic in the comment.

> "**老师们正在威胁罢工**, 你觉得对[**此**]该做什么?"

Answer (score 4):

What 什么
you 你
think 觉得
should 该
done 做
about 对
it 此

So, 对此 is used because of "about it".

Answer (score 0):

```
對此
```

此 is like a pronoun "this" in English for something mentioned before.

對 is like "refer to", "point to", "for", "about"

By adding 對此, it is to specify this question which is related to something mentioned before.

Answer (score -1):

I think it's just an emphasis. Actually you can just leave it out if the context is clear.